# Replicate data from Azure-Active-Directory to sql database

Tags: azure-active-directory

maybe I can find the solution deep inside the developer documetation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-developers-guide). But not on the surface, so I hope someone can ask the following question.

We do replicate data from on-premise active-directory to our database to store users, groups, units and configure features- and role-permissions to our applications. As we can't (at least not to start from scratch) authorize all features calling the azure-active-directory API I like to know if it is possible to replicate the needed objects from azure-ad like I can do from ad?

If yes, if someone has a link to any reference you will make my day while I continue seek for this information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we are able to replicate the data from Azure AD through the Azure AD Graph REST. However the Azure AD is a different with Active Directory on-premise. For example, there is no organizational units.

You can check the exposed object in Azure Active Directory via the link below:

[Entity and complex type reference | Graph API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference)

And to get started with Azure AD Graph REST, you can refer [Azure Active Directory Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api). Also since Microsoft is working on Microsoft Graph, if there is no such object in the Azure AD Graph REST, you may also check the [Microsoft Graph REST](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now I know it works and schedule research.